# Is there an easier, simple way to connect android studio to local host?

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a register request script. And as RiggsFolly mentioned before, I just keep repeating myself. So, **I want to know how would I connect Android Studio to my localhost server? I was just told params might not be the solution, and I've seen other answers be way to complicated for this simple task.**

**It seems like params isn't sending data over properly**. So I just want to know what should instead of params to send data to the php script. Now I've seen this script, and it looks to use an outside library that I couldn't import.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        String responseString = out.toString();
        out.close();
        //..more logic
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

I couldn't import the http library, so I need to know if their is a in-built way to use http requests.

At the moment, my RegisterRequest script look like this;

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.*.*:80/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);
        System.out.println(isAdmin);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Now, im using params.put to input the parameters into the php script, but the php doesn't seem to receive anything, and even spits out an undefined index error when I try to reference what it should be getting.

This is the php script. It WAS simple, but it just a mess of a code thats supposed to $_POST data into a "cresidentials" db. The rest of the code is just a hodge-podge of lines people wanted me to put in for debugging reasons.

```
<?php
    $db_host = 'localhost:3306';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'test';
    var_dump($_POST["username"]);//line 6
    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,'root',$db_pass,$db_name);
    if($con){
        echo "connection successful";
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["isAdmin"]) &&  isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $isAdmin = $_POST["isAdmin"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO cresidentials (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'sss',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    if(!$statement) 
    {
         printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); 
    }

    echo "success";
}
else
 echo "values not set";
?>
```

The $_POST is spitting an undefined index error. And no, RiggsFolly, just because I said undefined index doesn't mean you can try to dupe this question to my other question. Stop that.

I do not believe is it required for me to put my CreateUser script in here, unless you want to change its params to jsonobjects. I would like to know anyone's simple way of just connecting android studio to php and posting data inside. And try not to go on a huge encryption deal, I'm very new at this. By the way, the output is this;

> /System.out: ahhh /System.out: ahhhh /System.out: Admin
>   /Response Value:: 
>  Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   \Register.php on line 6
>       NULL
>       connection successfulvalues not set

I appreciate all help, thanks.

> This is the part where Riggs edits my entire question

Comment: in android you define and set `params`, but I cannot see that you actually use them/pass them to something, or get them via `getparams()`. Where and how do you use `RegisterRequest`?

Comment: @Jeff i thought params was an in-built function. hence why it turned blue when i used it, so i thought it was a keyword. It seems like params is first introduced after the URL

Comment: @Jeff RegisterRequest is used by CreateUser. A separate java class. Ill link you to a previous outdated question of mine that have the script in it, if you please

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, you're sending a GET request without any parameters at all:

```
httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
```

Judging by your "request" class I'm guessing you're trying to use Volley. In Volley you have to create a RequestQueue and add your request to it. See the guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/

Comment: I do have a requestqueue inside my CreateUser class. I did not post the script because the question is already length as it. And, i tried to use HttpClient, but nothing pops up. I was told its an external function i must add in, but i  couldn't add it in.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you tell me what to replace with what, because honestly, I haven't known what I was doing for the past 3 weeks on this project, and I'm gonna fail soon. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you're using `Volley`, you don't need `HttpClient`. If you're using `HttpClient`, you don't need `Volley`. You should try to not use more than one http client library in your project because it's just going to be confusing. Now, what's the problem with the version of the android app that sends uses `requestQueue.add` to send the request? You should probably post that as a separate question

Comment: The problem i am getting is this; yes, im using Volley, but it doesnt seem to post data to the php script. It runs the script, but $_POST gets nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375894/what-would-be-the-simplest-way-of-posting-data-to-a-php-script-from-android-u