# What would be the simplest way of posting data using Volley?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to use Volley to send 3 strings to a php script that sends it to a localhost server. I have this so far;

RegisterRequest;

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.*.*:80/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin,
                           Response.Listener<String> listener,
                           Response.ErrorListener errListener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,errListener);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

This is CreateUser;

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
        this.setTitle("Create User");
        final EditText username1 = findViewById(R.id.Createusername);
        final EditText password1 = findViewById(R.id.CreatePassword);
        final Switch isAdmin = findViewById(R.id.isadmin);
        final Button createuser = findViewById(R.id.createuserbtn);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response")){
            isAdmin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response Value: ", response);
                            if (response.equals("success")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                CreateUser.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                        }
                    }
                };Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener,errorListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });

    }
```

Now, the only error im getting is an Undefined index. And thats because Volley isnt sending data to the php script. The php script does work properly when data is sent to it, so my question is this; what changes do i have to make to my script for it to send the 3 strings over?

Comment: *Volley isnt sending data* - how do you know?

Comment: Because i used Postman with Post and it works perfectly. So something is on my android end not working. I have a previous question with an answer telling me to recreate my question and make it a volley question. So i did

Comment: "something is on my android end not working" - OK but why do you jump to the conclusion that volley isn't sending data? Is it even performing the request? Have you debugged the code to verify it is called with the expected values?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes i have. It just spits out Undefined index. Please refer to previous questions of mine

Comment: Where is your `addToRequestQueue` method ? Did you implement `AppController` class ?

Comment: I don't want to read previous questions. What spits out undefined index? What even is that error? Do you have some logcat output?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Android studio spits out Undefined Index. It means that the php script is returning a  error to android studio that it needs to use data it was never given

Comment: @CagriYalcin i do not know what that even is. I am sorry, I never used volley. I thought the CreateUser class adds to the registration queue

Comment: debugging does not mean to run the app and see what happens. I mean attach a debugger and set some breakpoints in the code to verify that the arguments are correct etc

Comment: @TimCastelijns They are. The arguments are correct.

Comment: @AlecHarvey see [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) tutorial

Comment: @CagriYalcin Thats wayyy to complicated for what im trying to accomplish. Do you know what i can do to fix this code without that many complications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mess with code or else it will be confusing for you to handle things properly.

So just make another class and use it in your activity.

Have a look at this class I have written, you can use it anywhere and for any type of data request.

```
public class SendData {

private Context context;
private String url;
private HashMap<String, String> data;

private OnDataSent onDataSent;

public void setOnDataSent(OnDataSent onDataSent) {
    this.onDataSent = onDataSent;
}

public SendData(Context context, String url, HashMap<String, String> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.url = url;
    this.data = data;
}

public void send(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(onDataSent != null){
                onDataSent.onSuccess(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(onDataSent != null){
                onDataSent.onFailed(error.toString());
            }
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.putAll(data);
            return map;
        }

    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, 0));
    RequestQueue requestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public interface OnDataSent{
    void onSuccess(String response);
    void onFailed(String error);
}

}
```

And now you can easily use it from any activity. Just give data in the constructor and use the interface to track the events this way

```
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("username", "");//define the value
    data.put("password", "");//define the value
    data.put("is_admin", "");//define the value

    SendData sendData = new SendData(this, "", data); //defie the context and url properly
    sendData.setOnDataSent(new SendData.OnDataSent() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            //parse the response 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(String error) {
            //something went wrong check the error
        }
    });
    sendData.send();
```

Comment: you should not use verbs as class names

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you please explain a bit ? i dont know about it

Comment: well this is just for the sake of demonstration ;)

Comment: @HarKal It would seem that you didn't define the value of the URL. Is this not a problem or must i define it when it is first declared. oh, scratch that, i see where to declare now.

Comment: @AlecHarvey off course you have to define the url, this is just a demo to explain you the approach you should have for making data requests. and i have written the comment also to define the context and url properly ;)

Comment: Ok. I have a question. How would i properly format the params.put method? is the "is_admin" the name of the variable android is looking for in the php script? or is it the variable it is going to send over?

Comment: this is what i have for context; final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username", username);//define the value
                data.put("password", password);//define the value
                data.put("is_admin", isadmin);//define the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183898/discussion-between-alec-harvey-and-har-kal).